# ACF plot title change?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, correlation

I wish to change the title that this simple `acf` plot would create, but I am unsure how to do so, as it defaults to the variable name `d.sales2`.

```
AutoCorrelation <- acf(d.sales.2)
plot(AutoCorrelation)
```

Comment: `acf(rnorm(100), main="Title")`, just as with a regular plot. See `?plot.acf()` for details.

Answer (score 6):

Answer goes to AkselA. Use `main` argument in `acf` as below:

```
# Simulation
d.sales.2 <- freeny$y

# Plotting
AutoCorrelation <- acf(d.sales.2, plot = FALSE)
plot(AutoCorrelation, main = "Freeny's Quarterly Revenue Time Series ACF")
```

Output:
[image: Times Series]: